# Is Play Services Analytics compatible with Gradle 3.3/AndroidX?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, androidx

When bumping my Android Gradle Plugin dependency (from 3.2.1 -> 3.3.x) I started seeing this problem:

`D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.media.RatingCompat$1`

This class is found in: `com.android.support:support-media-compat`
As suggested here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate I have added an explicit dependency to the AndroidX version of the lib: `androidx.media:media`.

This doesn't work (same issue).

Then I do:

```
gradlew app:dependencies
```

I see that `com.android.support:support-media-compat` is a transitive dependency coming from `com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics` (16.0.7, latest that I know of).

I have also tried excluding the transitive dependency:

```
implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.7') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

But this doesn't work (the support-v4 dependency still shows up as a transitive dependency).

**My versions**

1. com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1
2. Gradle 5.2.1

**Gradle properties:**

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=false
```

**Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be setting:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

so that transitive dependencies are converted for you.

Comment: Enabling jetifier revealed  a test library (org.robolectric:shadows-supportv4:4.1) causing issues and more classes that needed to be converted into Androidx. After doing this it all worked.